# UseContext can't find variable?

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I'm trying to understand useContext but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here, I get the error message "Can't find variable: Test" but in the tutorial I'm reading from it never says anything about needing to import/export other than what is in the code?
Thank you!

**App.js**

```
    import React, { createContext } from 'react';
    const Test = createContext()

    export default function App() {
  return (
    <Test.Provider value="hello">
        <Home/>
    </Test.Provider>  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {

    return(
        <Test.Consumer>
                <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
                  {value}
                </View>
        </Test.Consumer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ollie, not to be rude or anything, but please read the docs before posting the question: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext - it's totally fine to be confused about the docs, but state in your question that you've read it and don't understand it if so. Your skills will grow faster by doing things yourself.

Comment: Yeah should probably have a look at that rather than the other tutorial I looked at :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't exporting `Test` from `App.js`, so you can't just implicitly use it in `Home.js`.

I'd recommend moving it to another file, say, `contexts.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
const Test = React.createContext();
export {Test};
```

You can then do

```
import {Test} from './contexts';
```

in both (or all, in the future) of your other source files to refer to the same context type.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create the context in a separate file :

**test-context.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const TestContext = createContext();
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TestContext } from './test-context';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value="hello">
        <Home/>
    </TestContext.Provider>  
  );
}
```

In `TestContext.Consumer`, you must provide a function to consume the context value.

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TestContext } from './test-context';

export default const Home = () => {
  return (
    <TestContext.Consumer>
      value => (
        <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
          {value}
        </View>
      )
    </TestContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We often forget about old school rules, when reading docs about fancy libraries these days.

In your example, `Context` is just a JS object, in order to access `Test.Consumer`, `Test` must be in scope of the file.

So, you have to import `Test` object (context) on order to access the `Consumer` property.